# How to Break Coupled ODEs down to first order for Runge-Kutta

Tags: differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

My question might seem a bit simple. I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using Runge-Kutta method. I am having difficulty breaking down the equations into a system of first order ones required before applying RK45 to it because there is a third order differential of the same parameter "F" in both equations which I am not used to.

Equation 1
 $\left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}F \left( \eta \right) 
 \right) ^{n-1}{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{3}}}F \left( \eta
 \right) +{\frac {2\,n+2+ \left( 2\,n-1 \right) kF \left( \eta
 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}F \left( \eta
 \right) }{n+4}}-{\frac { \left( n+2+ \left( n+1 \right) k \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}\eta}}F \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{2
}}{n+4}}+G \left( \eta \right) =0$

Equation 2

${\frac { \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}F \left( \eta
 \right)  \right) ^{n-1} \left( n-1 \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3
}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{3}}}F \left( \eta \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}\eta}}G \left( \eta \right) }{\Pr\,{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}
{\eta}^{2}}}F \left( \eta \right) }}+ \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}F \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{n-1}{\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}G \left( \eta \right) +{\frac {2\,n+2+
 \left( 2\,n-1 \right) kF \left( \eta \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}
\eta}}G \left( \eta \right) }{n+4}}-{\frac {n+2\, \left( n+1 \right) k
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}\eta}}F \left( \eta \right)  \right) G
 \left( \eta \right) }{n+4}}=0
$

Boundary Conditions

$ G \left( 0 \right) =1, F \left( 0 \right)=F' \left( 0 \right) =0,G \left( \infty \right) =0,F' \left( \infty  \right) =0 $

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid cross-posts, or at least add links to the other sites where you asked the same identical question.